# Why is `&` needed to destructure a list of tuples during iteration?

Tags: rust

When iterating a list of tuples, the `&` is needed to make it work. Thus this will work ...

```
for &(a, b, c) in [("hello", 1.0, 5), ("world", 2.0, 2)].iter() {
    println!("{} {} {}", a, b, c);
}
```

but that won't ...

```
for (a, b, c) in [("hello", 1.0, 5), ("world", 2.0, 2)].iter() {
    println!("{} {} {}", a, b, c);
}

// type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, (&str, _, _)> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == (_, _, _)`:
// expected &-ptr,
found tuple [E0271]
```

I am sure it has to do with intricacies of the destructuring syntax that I have not yet fully internalised.

**Can you explain which syntactical truth is behind the ampersand ?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because the [`iter` method for an array `[T]`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) returns an [iterator that yields `&T` values](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html).  That's why the compiler says "`expected &-ptr, found tuple [E0271]`".

So why's that?  Well, *in general*, you can't copy `T`.  Unless the code assumes a more restrictive bound of `T: Copy` or `T: Clone`, it can only *move* values of type `T`.

This is a problem for arrays because there's no way to move a single element out of an array; doing so would invalidate the whole thing.

> **Aside**: `Vec` and co. get around this by implementing additional logic in `unsafe` blocks to make it work.  Containers may also provide `into_iter` which gives you an iterator that incrementally *consumes* the container, allowing you to move values out.

Because you want the array `iter` method to work for *all* arrays, it instead yields immutable references to each element in turn.

As a result, you're trying to destructure a `&(&str, f32, i32)`, not a `(&str, f32, i32)`, hence the additional `&`.  Rust doesn't like implicitness, so you have to *explicitly* destructure the reference.  This also helps make it clear that there's a dereference *and a copy* happening here.

Comment: Ok, but wait: Does it mean all my tuple members are actually copied into their respective slots a, b, and c ? I would have hoped I access them through a reference of the tuple.

Comment: They are copied.  Actually, *in general*, they are copied if copyable, or moved if not behind a reference; failing that, the compiler will shout at you. If you want a reference, you have to *ask* for a reference.  This is what the `ref` keyword is for: `&(ref a, ref b, ref c)`.  This, in a pattern, says: "the thing at this position?  Bind it *by reference* to a variable named `x`".  And yes, you can use this anywhere a pattern is valid: in match arms, `if let` and regular `let`.  Fun times!

Comment: @Byron: Oh!  I almost forgot.  You can also (with a recent `rustc`) remove the explicit call to `.iter()`.  There is now an [`IntoIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait which goes from a thing to its iterator.  Since you're iterating by-ref, change `[...].iter()` to `&[...]` (or `&mut [...]` for `[...].iter_mut()`).  This also works with a vector `v` with `v`, `&v`, and `&mut v` being equivalent to `v.into_iter()`, `v.iter()` and `v.iter_mut()` respectively.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification and for the updates on the new syntactical sugar. Sweet !