# What is the purpose of `&` before the loop variable?

Tags: reference, rust, pattern-matching, destructuring, ampersand

What is the purpose of `&` in the code `&i in list`? If I remove the `&`, it produces an error in `largest = i`, since they have mismatched types (where `i` is `&32` and `i` is `i32`). But how does `&i` convert `i` into `i32`?

```rust
fn largest(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    println!("{:?}", list);
    let mut largest = list[0];
    for &i in list {
        if i > largest {
            largest = i;
        }
    }
    largest
}

fn main() {
    let hey = vec![1, 3, 2, 6, 90, 67, 788, 12, 34, 54, 32];
    println!("The largest number is: {}", largest(&hey));
}
```

[**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5fb13521615b3b55c9f6dbaba49870c)

It seems like it is somehow dereferencing, but then why in the below code, is it not working?

```
fn main() {
    let mut hey: i32 = 32;
    let x: i32 = 2;
    hey = &&x;
}
```

It says:

```
4 |     hey = &&x;
  |           ^^^ expected i32, found &&i32
  |
  = note: expected type `i32`
             found type `&&i32`
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the function can be rewritten as `list.iter().copied().max().expect("empty list")`. Might be useful to you.

Comment: [Does this error message mean I can use pattern matching in for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50644111/3650362) is related.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So normally when you use `for i in list`, the loop variable `i` would be of type `&i32`.

But when instead you use `for &i in list`, you are not *dereferencing* anything, but instead **you are using pattern matching to explicitly *destructure* the reference** and that will make `i` just be of type `i32`.

See the Rust docs about the for-loop loop variable [being a pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops) and the [reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns) that we are using here. See also the Rust By Example chapter on [destructuring pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html).

An other way to solve this, would be to just keep `i` as it is and then comparing `i` to a reference to `largest`, and then dereferencing `i` before assigning to `largest`:

```
fn largest(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    println!("{:?}", list);
    let mut largest = list[0];
    for i in list {
        if i > &largest {
            largest = *i;
        }
    }
    largest
}
```

---

> ```
> fn main() {
>     let mut hey: i32 = 32;
>     let x: i32 = 2;
>     hey = &&x;
> }
> ```

This simply doesn't work, because here you are assigning `hey`, which is an `i32`, to a reference to a reference to an `i32`. This is quite unrelated to the pattern matching and destructuring in the loop variable case.

Answer (score 24):

**This is the effect of *destructuring***. I won't completely describe that feature here, but in short:

In many syntax contexts (`let` bindings, `for` loops, function arguments, ...) , Rust expects a "pattern". This pattern can be a simple variable name, but it can also contain some "destructuring elements", like `&`. Rust will then bind a value to this pattern. A simple example would be something like this:

```rust
let (a, b) = ('x', true);
```

On the right hand side there is a value of type `(char, bool)` (a tuple). This value is bound to the left hand pattern (`(a, b)`). As there is already a "structure" defined in the pattern (specifically, the tuple), that structure is removed and `a` und `b` bind to the tuple's elements. Thus, the type of `a` is `char` and the type of `b` is `bool`.

This works with a couple of structures, including arrays:

```rust
let [x] = [true];
```

Again, on the right side we have a value of type `[bool; 1]` (an array) and on the left side we have a pattern in the form of an array. The single array element is bound to `x`, meaning that the type of `x` is `bool` and *not* `[bool; 1]`!

And unsurprisingly, this also works for references!

```rust
let foo = 0u32;
let r = &foo;
let &c = &foo;
```

Here, `foo` has the type `u32` and consequently, the expression `&foo` has the type `&u32`. The type of `r` is also `&u32`, as it is a simple `let` binding. The type of `c` is `u32` however! That is because the "reference was destructured/removed" by the pattern.

**A common misunderstanding is that syntax in patterns has exactly the opposite effect of what the same syntax would have in expressions!** If you have a variable `a` of type `[T; 1]`, then the expression `[a]` has the type `[[T; 1]; 1]` → it *adds* stuff. However, if you bind `a` to the pattern `[c]`, then `y` has the type `T` → it *removes* stuff.

```rust
let a = [true];    // type of `a`: `[bool; 1]`
let b = [a];       // type of `b`: `[[bool; 1]; 1]`
let [c] = a;       // type of `c`: `bool`
```

This also explains your question:

> It seems like it is somehow dereferencing, but then why in the below code, it is not working?
>
> ```rust
> fn main() {
>    let mut hey:i32 = 32;
>    let x:i32 = 2;
>    hey = &&x;
> }
> ```

Because you use `&` on the expression side, where it *adds* a layer of references.

---

So finally about your loop: when iterating over a slice (as you do here), the iterator yields reference to the slice's elements. So in the case `for i in list {}`, `i` has the type `&i32`. But the assignment `largest = i;` requires a `i32` on the right hand side. You can achieve this in two ways: either dereference `i` via the dereference operator `*` (i.e. `largest = *i;`) or destructure the reference in the loop pattern (i.e. `for &i in list {}`).

---

*Related questions*:

- [Iterating over a slice's values instead of references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613725/iterating-over-a-slices-values-instead-of-references-in-rust)
- [Why is `&` needed to destructure a list of tuples during iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405400/why-is-needed-to-destructure-a-list-of-tuples-during-iteration)

Comment: Thank you for such a clear answer. I think it might be helpful to view the destructuring as an algebra 'cancellation' operation. For example, in `let &c = &foo` - if you 'cancel' the `&`, the `c` is set to `foo`. "Reference of c is set to reference of foo", so `c` is set to `foo`.

Comment: Thank your for this explanation. The example was super helpful, imo the better anwer