# How pattern matching in Rust works with `let` statement

Tags: rust

Why does snippet `pattern_matching_2` and `pattern_matching_3` work whereas `pattern_matching_1` doesn't? The compiler suggests that `let &x = &foo` moves the string hello, which I'm aware of and don't see where the problem is -- I'm not using `foo` anyway, and compiler doesn't complain anything about `pattern_matching_3`, which moves the string hello as well.

The example snippets are adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57339533/7881370), which didn't answer my question.

The code snippets:

```rust
fn pattern_matching_1() {
    let foo = String::from("hello");
    let &x = &foo;
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn pattern_matching_2() {
    let foo = 12;
    let &x = &foo;
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn pattern_matching_3() {
    let foo = String::from("hello");
    let x = foo;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

The compiler error of `pattern_matching_1`:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:26:14
   |
26 |     let &x = &foo;
   |         --   ^^^^
   |         ||
   |         |data moved here
   |         |move occurs because `x` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |         help: consider removing the `&`: `x`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he compiler suggests that `let &x = &foo` moves the string hello, which I'm aware of and don't see where the problem is

The problem is that you've given the compiler an immutable reference to a variable (`&foo`) and then asked it to move away the underlying data. Which is not an operation that is permitted by immutable references.

To make this more explicit, extract the moving-out part into another function:

```
fn pattern_matching_1_helper(r: &String) {
    let &x = r;
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn pattern_matching_1() {
    let foo = String::from("hello");
    pattern_matching_1_helper(&foo);
}
```

I hope it's obvious that `pattern_matching_1_helper` cannot compile on its own. But the combined version in your code is really no different.

`pattern_matching_2` compiles because `i32` is `Copy`, so the compiler doesn't need to move.

Comment: I don't quite agree that the original version is no different. In your example, it's clear that `r` lives for the whole function, so we can't move out the underlying data. In the original example, the reference is a temporary that only lives for the duration of the statement, so moving out the underlying data wouldn't create any dangling reference in the original case, and the original code is, in fact, safe (albeit pointless).

Comment: To clarify, I know that your code is the same _from the viewpoint of the borrow checker_ – the reference lives until the end of the statement, so you can't move the data out during the statement. However, the reason for this isn't that the case are "no different", but that someone decided that this is how it works.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The lifetime of the reference is not relevant. What is relevant is that the compiler will not move a value through a reference. You can move from a variable. You **can never** move through a reference.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase to clarify my point. Rust has the fundamental rule that references can never become invalid. As a consequence, the code in this answer is invalid: After moving the string, `r` would be an invalid reference. The code in the original post doesn't have that problem, though – even if Rust allowed moving the string in that case, we wouldn't end up with any invalid references. (And I'm not only splitting hairs here – I think this distinction is actually the cause of the confusion here.)

Comment: Sorry I failed to understand that "then asked it to move away the underlying data" is a problem. I no longer use the moved data (`foo`) after all. Why is this a problem? Thanks

Comment: @SvenMarnach It's not about references becoming invalid. It's about what you're allowed to do with a reference. If you do `&variable`, you get a shared reference, a `&T` (or `&String` in this particular case). And you simply cannot use a shared reference to move away the underlying data. The reference is shared, there might be another reference pointing to the same data. *Could* the compiler figure out in this particular case that there isn't, and that the referenced variable is no longer used? Yes it could, but **why would it**? In 99.9% of real-world use cases, it would be too complicated.

Comment: So it's simply not worth the specification and implementation effort to make this particular case work, when the solution for the programmer is to **simplify the code** by turning it into version 3 of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn pattern_matching_3() {
    let foo = String::from("hello");
    let x = foo;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This works because `foo` is moved into `x`, so `foo` is no longer a usable variable. It's ok to move data from the variable that owns it, as long as that variable is never used again.

```
fn pattern_matching_1() {
    let foo = String::from("hello");
    let &x = &foo;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This doesn't work because `foo` is still the owner of the string but you are trying to move the data out of `x`, which has only borrowed it.

`pattern_matching_2` works because `i32` is `Copy`, so nothing is moved.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean by "but you are trying to move the data out of `x`". As per [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements), `let PATTERN = EXPRESSION;`, `let x = foo;`should be equivalent to `let &x = &foo;`. Why is `let &x = &foo;` false?